# how to export excel to a specific directory or file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using  tableExport https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport, i'm sucessfully able to export table .

using this line of code

```
$("table").tableExport();
```

i'm doing it on `server` so i want to `save` the `file` to a specific `folder` so, that i can send this `excel` using `mail` by using `phpMailer`

my question is: **is there any way to export excel to a specific folder** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is javascript and this is not run on the server but in the visitors browser. So any export is only possible on the visitors computer.

In other words: You cannot save that file to the server (and send it by mail).

Comment: then what could be the possible solution?

Comment: i'm using `php` as a server side language, that means i have to do it using `phpExcel` only , i'm fear to use it to make `table`. but i'm able to read content from `excel` easily

Comment: You have to do it on the server side. There's no information about the server programming language given, but you can normally export the data as a simple csv file and send that. Or you find a class/module/plugin that can export Excel files.

Comment: i have missed the plugin name which you are talking about.. can you say once again... please

Answer (score 0):

You can generate and save the excel file using PHP itself. JavaScript wont help in file transfer. You can use [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) for this,

This [article](http://phpflow.com/php/export-html-table-data-to-excel-csv-png-and-pdf-using-jquery-plugin/) will help you more to achieve this with jQuery and PHP. Hope this helps